# Convert String to Tuple, Special Formatting in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, tuples

For a test app, I'm trying to convert a special type of string to a tuple. The string is always in the following format, with an int (n>=1) followed by a character.

**Examples of Input String**:

```
"2s"

"13f"

"1b"
```

**Examples of Desired Output Tuples (Int, Char)**:

```
(2, 's')

(13, 'f')

(1, 'b')
```

Any pointers would be extremely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `readS` to parse the int and get the rest of the string:

```
readTup :: String -> (Int, Char)
readTup s = (n, head rest)
  where [(n, rest)] = reads s
```

a safer version would be:

```
maybeReadTup :: String -> Maybe (Int, Char)
maybeReadTup s = do
  [(n, [c])] <- return $ reads s
  return (n, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

parseTuple :: String -> Maybe (Int, Char)
parseTuple s = do
  (int, (char:_)) <- listToMaybe $ reads s

  return (int, char)
```

This uses the `Maybe` Monad to express the possible parse failure. Note that if the `(char:_)` pattern fails to match (i.e., if there is only a number with no character after it), this gets translated into a `Nothing` result (this is due to how `do` notation works in Haskell. It calls the `fail` function of the `Monad` if pattern matches fail. In the case of `Maybe a`, we have `fail _ = Nothing`). The function also evaluates to `Nothing` if `reads` can't read an `Int` at the beginning of the input. If this happens, `reads` gives `[]` which is then turned into `Nothing` by `listToMaybe`.